# find name from realm extended object with a common method

Tags: c#, generics, realm

I want to find a specific key from my models that we have created for different entities.

```
public class Contact : RealmObject{


   [PrimaryKey]
    public Id {get;set;}

    public ContactName {get; set;}

    public String 


  } 


public class Customer : RealmObject{

    PrimaryKey]
    public Id {get;set;}

    public CustomerName {get; set;}

  }

public class User : RealmObject{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public Id {get;set;}

    public UserName {get; set;}

  }
```

Here `item` parameter could be Contact , Customer or User and i want to find the Name using following function if possible

```
  public void getName(Realm rObj  , T item) Where T : RealmObject {


  }
```

we do not want to create duplicates method to find name for each entity and we are not find it based on any `primary key`

```
 public void getName(Realm obj, Contact contact){


    Contact data = realm.All<Contact>().Where(c=>c.ContactName == contact.ContactName)).FirstOrDefault();

  }
```

Comment: Can you modify the models at all?  Rename the fields to `Name` (after all, the context of what is being named is already present on the object itself anyway), and have them all implement an `INameable` interface which has a `Name` property.  Constrain `T` to be of `INameable` and you can reference that property.

Comment: well i wish i could do that :) but that the main problem that i can't rename it however i do understand your proposed solution. is there any other way ?

Comment: I guess at that point you're looking at a reflection type situation.  Maybe you can parse out the type name and use it to construct the property name?  Or have a `switch` of known types and property names?  Being able to cleanly design the models really seems like the more ideal approach, not being able to modify them *at all* is going to be a bit limiting.

Comment: can you provide the example related to it and would reflection reduced the performance?

Comment: @David even if we use `INameable` then this statement wont work too   `INameable data = realm.All<T>().Where(c=>c.Name == arg.Name)).FirstOrDefault();` as `c.Name` might be not known to `RealmObject`

Comment: Would `INameable` even be used in that statement?  What should this method be *doing* in the first place?  It's called `getName` but it doesn't return anything.  If it's supposed to return a name, then constraining `T` to `INameable` and returning a `string` would make sense to me.  The method would only need to know about `INameable`, it wouldn't need to know about things like `Contact`.  Would it just be `return item.Name`?